# service lifecycle on android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler

I create a service and then start it on main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, MQTTservice.class));
}
```

in my service class at onCreate() method i logged it:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: 1");
    connection = new MqttConnection();
}
```

as you see in this method i create new instance of MqttConnection class that extended from Thread class.in the constructor of MqttConnection class i do log again:

```
public MqttConnection() {
    Log.i("==>", "constructor MqttConnection: service");
    // create a handler
    msgHandler = new MsgHandler();
    msgHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null,CONNECT));
}
```

as you see in this method i create new instance of MsgHandler class that extended from Handler class.in the constructor of MsgHandler class again i do log :

```
MsgHandler() {
    Log.i("==>", "MsgHandler: constructor");
}
```

and in handleMessage on MsgHandler class:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    Log.i("==>", "handleMessage: MsgHandler"+ msg.what);
}
```

I override onStartCommand method of my service like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: service");

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Start the MQTT Thread.
    connection.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and log it.as you can see i have started my thread (MqttConnection() class). when i run this code i just get this log:

```
onCreate: 1
onStartCommand: service
```

why other my log does not appear?

Comment: your question doesn't seem related to service lifecycle at all, the problem seems to be your MqttConnection class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a isRunning in MqttConnection:

```
class MqttConnection extends Thread {
    private boolean running;
    private MsgHandler msgHandler;

    MqttConnection() {
        Log.e("==>", "constructor MqttConnection: service");
        // create a handler
        msgHandler = new MsgHandler();
        msgHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, 1));
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
```

Change onStartCommand method of MQTTservice like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: service");

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Start the MQTT Thread:
    if (!connection.isRunning()) {
        connection.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Log:

```
==>: constructor MqttConnection: service
==>: MsgHandler: constructor
MQTT_SERVICE_TAG: onStartCommand: service
==>: handleMessage: MsgHandler1
```

I hope this helps.